# How can I detect a 404 url when HttpWebResponse response.StatusCode is 301

Tags: c#, redirect

The HttpWebResponse returns status code 301 but when you visit the url you get a 404 not found

I use this code to detect if a url is valid

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.trasportale.it/categoria_construction/in-cava/");
webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse()

bool success = ((int)response.StatusCode) >= 200 && ((int)response.StatusCode) < 400;
```

The response.StatusCode is 301 but when visiting the actual url you get a 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Request you are making to `https://www.trasportale.it/categoria_construction/in-cava/` returns `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` in the browser as well, and redirects you to `https://trasportale.it/categoria_construction/in-cava/` (without the `www.`) which then gives a `HTTP 404 Not Found`.

Comment: So I shall get the redirection via response.GetResponseHeader("Location") and perform a similar check in order to get the final status code. Correct?

Comment: Just set `HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect ` to `true`. The client will then automatically follow the redirect.
Be aware that `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse` will throw a `WebException` if the server returns `HTTP 404`. You can inspect the Http-Code on the `Status` property of the raised exception.